# how to avoid drag and drop for a specific list item in sap.m.list

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, sapui5

I have implemented drag n drop for sap.m.list as below. Now I need to avoid drag an drop for specific items  of the list. How to stop drag n drop feature for only specific items

```
 jQuery.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-core');
 jQuery.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-widget');  
 jQuery.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-mouse');  
 jQuery.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-draggable');  
 jQuery.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-sortable');  
   my.clauseRendering = function (oControl) {
          //inject control  
          //debugger;
          test = this;
             test.oControl = oControl;  
         };  
         my.clauseRendering.prototype = {  
             onAfterRendering: function () { 
              $("#clauseList-listUl").addClass('ui-sortable');


                  $("#clauseList-listUl").sortable({
                         //connectWith : ".ui-sortable"
                          cancel: '',
                     start: function(event, ui) {
                      debugger;
                  ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
                   },
              // sync the model after reordering in the box
                 stop: function(event, ui) {
                  //debugger;
                 ----
                }

                     }).disableSelection();

           }
   var ClauseList=sap.ui.getCore().byId("clauseList");
         ClauseList.addDelegate(new my.clauseRendering(ClauseList));
```

here the html view for the list is like the list will take  tag with class "ui-sortable"  so that all the items in the list are draggable . Now I need to stop drag and drop for specific items in that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize the sortable with the cancel option:

```
$(".ui-sortable").sortable(
   { cancel: ".non-draggable" }
);
```

Or you can set it later:

```
$( ".ui-sortable" ).sortable( "option", "cancel", ".non-draggable" );
```

Of course instead of the "non-draggable" class you can use any selector

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
    items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.